# Exporting "datareader" data

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to this site, but find the information here very helpful. I have an issue where I am returning results from a sql 8 db to a grid control on the website written in C#. The results are very large, I am talking about 800K rows! It was working fine up until a few months ago. I'm not sure what the admins might have done with my resources of memory. So now I have limited the report to only three months of data, but even still it takes about 20 minutes(when working) to retrieve any data. I also have the option to export the data as well so I cannot use a data reader to stream the data. In a staging environment everything works fine, but in production it does not. I am out of thoughts at this point. The dba says its an apllication issue where I say its a database issue. Here is a sample of the code:

```
// Get Data

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

con.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString";
con.Open();

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);

con.Close();

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dg.DataBind();
dg.RenderControl(htw);

Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: When life gives you a lemon..fire the dba!

Comment: You need to show us the stored procedure.

Comment: Have you tried to profile your app to see what time is spent where? You can do that buy simply adding few logging statements.

Comment: Also why aren't you making use of `using` statements?  How are you cleaning up or disposing of these objects?  You should wrap your con object, the cmd object and any readers inside of a `using` statement.  It will get disposed of properly.

Comment: You should create a real excel file instead of this giant html-table. I recommend [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439).

Comment: Well the page is limited to <>100 lines of code, but the other lines are loaded so the client can search for specific items. Like I mentioned before, I have the option of exporting the file to an excel sheet (comma delimited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be timing out in the database or in the web site.   Definitely do some performance tuning, and perhaps look into an interface where only a small selection of the rows are returned at a time.

Isn't there a 65k rows limit on Excel sheet as well?